# Connection issue in quickstart.js

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm getting this error every time I make an outbound call. The only thing I changed in `quickstart.js` was `data.identity` to match my clients username and now my calls don't connect.

> Device callback handlers (connect, error, offline, incoming, cancel, ready, disconnect) have been deprecated and will be removed in the next breaking release. Instead, the EventEmitter interface can be used to set event listeners. Example: device.on('ready', handler)

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Hey Nat.  Welcome to SO. Can you give more information? What `quickstart.js` are you referring to (maybe link it)? What changes did you do in detail? What are you trying to achieve with your changes? :)

Comment: I'm trying to make voice calls in my web application using Twilio Programmable Voice service. It works in the demo but when I change the data.identity value to the username of my clients the calls don't connect https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/quickstart

Comment: The documentation link you sent does not include anything `identity` (I looked search the whole page). It's hard to give advice without knowing what you're dealing with and without seeing some actual code. :)

Comment: If you are using the Twilio Function to create the token used by the client, the Twilio Token Function has a constant with a hardcoded identity that is returned to the client. That is where the identity is set in the quickstart (the value of data.identity).

https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-js/blob/master/public/quickstart.js

Comment: Thank you, I was able to generate a token and also set the identity with the function you mentioned.